# Question on solving a Logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

$\ln(x+3)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \ln (4x-3)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \ln (5)$

So I understand that in order to solve this log function, I would have to square the square roots to simplify the equation.

But how does the number $e$ come into play?

Comment: The problem would have been totally different if it were, say, $$\ln^{\frac{1}{2}}(x+3) + \ln^{\frac{1}{3}} (4x-3) = \ln (5)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\log A^{1/2}=\frac12\log A\;,\;\;A>0$$

$$\log A+\log B=\log(AB)$$

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to square the square roots.

$ln(A)+ln(B)=ln(C)$

But we know that $ln(A)+ln(B)=ln(AB)$

So:

$ln(AB)=ln(C)$

$e^{AB}=e^{C}$      (Note: This is where e comes into **play**)

But we know that:

> $a^b=a^c$
>   $b=c$

Therefore we can say that :

$e^{AB}=e^{C}$

$(AB)=C$

Comment: Ops its a typo, thanks for showing it...lemme edit it

Comment: I got x=5 after simplifying it but when graphing it I get x=2

Comment: I edited my answer, There was a mistake (Sorry). Now I corrected it.

Comment: So essentially ((x+3)^0.5)((4x-3)^0.5) = 5?

Comment: Indeed so, @mathemator...or easier: $$\log[(x+3)(4x-3)]=2\log 5=\log 25\iff (x+3)(4x-3)=25$$ , using the hints I wrote in my answer.